# Truncate multi-dimensional array to include certain values only

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array and I need to truncate this array down to only contain the information I need.

The reference date is in the following format;

```
    $reference_date = '20120624';
```

I need to turn this array...

```
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(2) "15"
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-06-24 08:00:00"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-06-24 17:00:59"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(2) "28"
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-07-26 18:00:00"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-07-26 22:00:59"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(2) "31"
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-07-28 00:00:00"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-07-28 23:59:59"
      }
    }
```

into this...

```
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(2) "15"
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-06-24 08:00:00"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-06-24 17:00:59"
      }
```

There can be more than one array with the same date (different times).  I need to preserve these as well.

I have tried various ways of unsetting but my understanding is just not there yet.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$reference_date = '20120624';
$reference_date = substr($reference_date, 0, 4).'-'.substr($reference_date, 4, 2).'-'.substr($reference_date, 6, 2);

$result = array();
foreach($data as $item){
   if(substr($item['start_time'], 0, 10) == $reference_date || substr($item['end_time'], 0, 10) == $reference_date)
       $result[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: Hey this works great.  If only I knew how it works.  The first part looks like pattern matching.. first position for 2 chars, after 4 positions for 2, and then after 6 for 2... the rest is la-la.  :(